# Oracle SQL Developer report to make DDL of DB object

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, ddl

I've wrote a report for SQL Developer to generate the DDL of a DB object.

```
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL(UPPER(:OBJECT_TYPE),UPPER(:OBJECT_NAME),UPPER(:OBJECT_SCHEMA)) DDL FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
select DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL (UPPER('CONSTRAINT'),UPPER(CONSTRAINT_NAME),UPPER(:OBJECT_SCHEMA)) AS "DDL OGGETTI DIPENDENTI" from DBA_CONSTRAINTS where OWNER like UPPER(:OBJECT_SCHEMA) and TABLE_NAME like UPPER(:OBJECT_NAME) and CONSTRAINT_TYPE not like 'R'
UNION ALL
select DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL (UPPER('REF_CONSTRAINT'),UPPER(CONSTRAINT_NAME),UPPER(:OBJECT_SCHEMA)) from DBA_CONSTRAINTS where OWNER like UPPER(:OBJECT_SCHEMA) and TABLE_NAME like UPPER(:OBJECT_NAME) and CONSTRAINT_TYPE like 'R'
UNION ALL
select DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL (UPPER('INDEX'),UPPER(INDEX_NAME),UPPER(:OBJECT_SCHEMA)) from DBA_INDEXES where OWNER like UPPER(:OBJECT_SCHEMA) and TABLE_NAME like UPPER(:OBJECT_NAME) 
UNION ALL
select DBMS_METADATA.GET_DEPENDENT_DDL (UPPER('COMMENT'),UPPER(TABLE_NAME),UPPER(:OBJECT_SCHEMA)) from DBA_COL_COMMENTS where OWNER like UPPER(:OBJECT_SCHEMA) and TABLE_NAME like UPPER(:OBJECT_NAME) AND COMMENTS is not null GROUP BY TABLE_NAME
UNION ALL
select DBMS_METADATA.GET_DEPENDENT_DDL (UPPER('OBJECT_GRANT'),UPPER(TABLE_NAME),UPPER(:OBJECT_SCHEMA)) from DBA_TAB_PRIVS where OWNER like UPPER(:OBJECT_SCHEMA) and TABLE_NAME like UPPER(:OBJECT_NAME) GROUP BY TABLE_NAME
UNION ALL
select DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL (UPPER('SYNONYM'),UPPER(TABLE_NAME),UPPER('PUBLIC')) from DBA_SYNONYMS where TABLE_OWNER like UPPER(:OBJECT_SCHEMA) and TABLE_NAME like UPPER(:OBJECT_NAME) GROUP BY TABLE_NAME
UNION ALL
select DBMS_METADATA.GET_DEPENDENT_DDL (UPPER('TRIGGER'),UPPER(TABLE_NAME),UPPER(:OBJECT_SCHEMA)) from DBA_TRIGGERS where TABLE_OWNER like UPPER(:OBJECT_SCHEMA) and TABLE_NAME like UPPER(:OBJECT_NAME) GROUP BY TABLE_NAME;
```

The result type of function DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL is CLOB.

The problem is when i copy the strings output in notepad or word:

- If I choose TABLE for report style every row of the output is quoted with " ". for example: **"** CREATE TABLE "MWPROD"."ORDINI" ... TABLESPACE "MWPROD_TBSDAT" ;**"**
- If I choose SCRIPT for report style some rows are truncate.

I want found a solution for generate a clean output with complete rows without quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the DDL is quoted by the database - it's to account for idiot developers - sorry, developers who name tables with reserved words, like "TABLE", or for folks that need case sensitive object names

For the truncated script output, use the [SET LONG](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12040.htm#i2699121) command in your script.

SET LONG {80 | n}
Sets maximum width (in bytes) for displaying CLOB, LONG, NCLOB and XMLType values; and for copying LONG values.